# How to extract a tag link using regular expression (REGEX - C#)

Tags: c#, regex

I have so far this:

```
<a href="(http://www.imdb.com/title/tt\d{7}/)".*?>.*?</a>
```

c#

```
ArrayList imdbUrls = matchAll(@"<a href=""(http://www.imdb.com/title/tt\d{7}/)"".*?>.*?</a>", html);
private ArrayList matchAll(string regex, string html, int i = 0)
{
  ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
  foreach (Match m in new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.Multiline).Matches(html))
    list.Add(m.Groups[i].Value.Trim());
  return list;
}
```

I'm trying to extract imdb link from an HTML page
what is wrong with this regex expression?

The main idea of this is to search in google for a movie and then look for a link to imdb in the results

Comment: I have no idea about `c#` but the inner `""` looks funny there to me...

Comment: its double couse of C# its like \"

Comment: Then why are the enclosing (outer) `"` not escaped the same way? Those are meant to be regex delimiters?

Comment: I fixed it so match just RE without c#

Comment: Maybe the slashes (`/`) have to be escaped. I suggest you try a regex vaidator. Good ones explain details of the matching process.

Comment: @AlexKapustian do you want to only get the string?

Comment: yes I want to get only the string (the link to the page)

Comment: Please show the line of C# code that uses this regex.  It is likely a character escaping issue.  You may have to double backslashes for them to get passed to the regex engine.  Also note that `.` matches any character, so you need to escape it to match a literal period.

Comment: You can try HAP (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com) I suppose

Comment: Use an HTML parser, not regex. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/399649

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is not a good choice for parsing HTML files.HTML is not strict nor is it regular with its format.

Use [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).You can use this code to retrieve it using `HtmlAgilityPack`

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(yourStream);

List<string> anchorImdbList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")//this xpath selects all anchor tags
                  .Select(p => p.Attributes["href"].Value)
                  .Where(x=>Regex.IsMatch(x,@".*?www\.imdb\.com.*?"))
                  .Select(y=>y)
                  .ToList<string>();
```

Comment: It dosen't work...
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
I'm trying to parse: http://www.google.com/search?q=imdb+The Awakening 2011  Une

Comment: @AlexKapustian this may be becuz some anchor tag may be without `href`..try the edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
string tag = "tag of the link";
string emptystring = Regex.Replace(tag, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```

Update :

```
string emptystring = Regex.Replace(tag, @"<[^>]*>", string.Empty);
```

Comment: I think that this won't work cause I need to extract the link from a page that has many tags like this <>

Answer (score 0):

You must escape the forward slashes. Try:

```
<a href="(http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt\d{7}\/)".*?>.*?<\/a>
```

If you need to parse out html elements from a complex page, regexes will be very cumbersome. Try the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) as others have suggested.